# Delete 2 tables with FK rlsp through WCF

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wcf

I have 2 tables, BookingDetails & VenueAvaiability. 
VenueID is a PK in VenueAvaillability, FK for BookingDetails.

In my ui for aspx, it will call the WCF service to perform the delete. When I click the button, i want to delete VenueID from BookingDetails and delete the whole row in VenueAvaillability.

I got

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'
```

Anyone can help me?

//in my WCF

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER Table BookingDetails DROP 
Constraint FK_BookingDetails_VenueAvailability FOREIGN KEY(VenueID) 
REFERENCES VenueAvailability(VenueID) ON DELETE SET NULL 
WHERE BookingID=@BookingID", con);        
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", venueInfo.BookingID);
```

In aspx.cs

```
DeleteVenueAvailability venueInfo = new DeleteVenueAvailability();

venueInfo.BookingID = lblBookingID.Text;
```

Comment: Why would you need an "ALTER TABLE" for simple data manipulation?

Comment: Update venueId to null (since it's a foreignkey column(assuming you allow nulls)), and then delete the row from venueavailability.

Comment: All these stuff for a delete? Something is wrong here!

Comment: i am sorry because i am new to coding.. @scheien, thanks! i think i get it

Comment: @user3111115: your constraint looks ok, so just try to delete the row in VenueAvailabilities and see how that works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have the foreign key to set NULL into BookingDetails.VenueId when the corresponding row in VenueAvailabilities are deleted.

So why not just do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM VenueAvailabilities WHERE VenueId = @VenueId;
```

You just need to get the VenueId from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what do you want to achieve by saying "Through WCF". What I suggest is that to carry out all the stuffs at Sql end and call that query as SP from front end. Simple!!

What I observe from the question is that you want to clean the VenueAvaiability and alter BookingDetails.

So, here's my suggestion:

1. Build your query so that it will delete all rows from booking availability after making a temp table or backing up some where else.
2. Alter table booking availability and delete id column.
3. Now its safe to run a Truncate query on VenueAvaiability, since all references are already deleted from the referenced table..

Comment: He wants to delete a specific row in VenueAvailabilities, and remove the foreign key in BookingDetails, based on a given BookingId. I guess he don't want to remove all rows in VenueAvailabilities.